# jQuery for loop to toggle id

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to dynamically change the background of my page using the jquery waypoint plugin (which tells you when an element is at the top or bottom of the viewport). My HTML is simple - I have multiple headings with the id of `#part1',`#part2' and so on and so forth. When `part[x]` is at the top of the viewport, I want `img[x]` to be displayed.

The following code works:

```
$("#part2").waypoint(function(event, direction) {
   if (direction === 'down') {
      $(".container").attr("id", "img2");
   }
   else {
      $(".container").attr("id", "img2");
   }
});
```

However, I have 18 'parts' and I don't want this code 18 times. I tried using a `for` loop
like this:

```
var chapters = $("[id^='part']");

for (var i=1; i<=chapters.length; i++){

    $("#part[i]").waypoint(function(event, direction) {
       if (direction === 'down') {
          $(".container").attr("id", "img[i]");
       }
       else {
          $(".container").attr("id", "img[i]");
       }
    });
}
```

But again, not working. Is it possible to escape the selector with square brackets like I've done? If not, what's the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm confused as to why you're performing an if/else that has the same actions for both conditions

Comment: @popnoodles Yes that's redundant at the moment, but while I'm still writing the code I just wanted the option of having a separate condition if the user is scrolling up vs down.

Comment: and how does changing .container's ID end up showing a different image ?

Comment: @Alnitak I have CSS rules for img1 / img2 / etc which sets the background to a different image for each. I've since changed them to classes as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the waypoint plugin is written correctly and handles multiple elements:

```
$("[id^='part']").waypoint(function(event, direction) {
    $(".container").attr('id', this.id.replace('part', 'img'));
});
```

add direction checks as required.

I'm not familiar with this plugin but the key part is that you should be able to bind the waypoint plugin to multiple elements, and then within the event handler `this` *should* be the element that triggered the event, whose ID is then just `this.id`.

NB: just changing the ID on `.container` wouldn't normally change the image on it, unless you've got a stack of CSS rules that look like:

```
#img1 { background-image: ... }
#img2 { background-image: ... }
...
```

However in that case you should use classes instead of IDs - it's much more normal for the ID of an element to be constant through its lifetime and for its CSS classes to change.

If `.container` has no other CSS classes it would make sense to give it a fixed ID of `container` instead and use a variant of the above code:

```
$("[id^='part']").waypoint(function(event, direction) {
    $("#container").attr('class', this.id.replace('part', 'img'));
});
```

The constraint on not having any other CSS classes is that since `class` can contain multiple values it's far simpler to just completely overwrite the class list than it is to remove the previous class (whatever that was) and then add the new one.

Comment: I like this answer the best, cuts way down on the amount of code used and has the same effect as using the `for` loop. You're correct, I had those CSS rules for the IDs, I'll change them to classes.

Comment: Can I just ask for a quick bit of clarification - with the `.attr('class', this.id.replace('part', 'img'))`, can you basically put anything instead of `this.id.replace()`? Even a function?

Comment: sure, you can put lots of other things there, including a function that'll be passed the current value and whose return value will become the new value.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it like this

```
for (var i=1; i<=chapters.length; i++){

    $("#part" + i).waypoint(function(event, direction) {
       if (direction === 'down') {
          $(".container").attr("id", "img" + i);
       }
       else {
          $(".container").attr("id", "img" + i);
       }
    });
}
```

instead of separate ids I would use css classes and doing like that you'll don't need a loop

Answer (score 0):

Instead if using square brackets, why not:

```
$("#part" + i)
"img" + i
```

You then just select by id, and are creating the id dynamically.